# Using for loops with if-else statement

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to complete some homework but I'm stuck on this question.
Not too familiar with using R or coding in general.
Basically we are given two variables:

```
PredictedTemperature = c(-10, -11, -8, -3, 4, 4, 2) 

DaysOfTheWeek = c('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday')
```

So, we had to come with code that combines for-loops with if-else statements. I've tried multiple ways with no success. The end result should be  a response of a pasted statement saying that 'the temperature will be warmer/cooler/same by' (degrees) 'on a' (specific day)

The code I´ve got so far is shown below and the variable in the for-loop is set to day:

```
for (day in 2:7) {
    if(PredictedTemperature[day+1] - PredictedTemperature[day] > 0){
        tempDiff = PredictedTemperature[day+1] - PredictedTemperature[day]
        printText = paste('The temperature on', DaysOfTheWeek, 'should warm up by', tempDiff, 'degrees')
        print(printText)}
    else{if(PredictedTemperature[day+1] - PredictedTemperature[day] <= 0){
        tempDiff = PredictedTemperature[day+1] - PredictedTemperature[day]
        printText = paste('The temperature on', DaysOfTheWeek, 'should cool down by', tempDiff, 'degrees')
        print(printText)}
    else{
        tempDiff = PredictedTemperature[day+1] - PredictedTemperature[day]
        printText = paste('The temperature on', DaysOfTheWeek, 'will be the same as yesterday')
        print(printText)}}}
```

I've got the days mostly right, except the days should *exclude* Monday and have all other days, starting from Tuesday and their changes in temperature.
Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirement was not very clear, but based on my understanding this might do the trick:

```
for(day in 1:7) {
  if(day==7){next}
  tempDiff = PredictedTemperature[day+1] - PredictedTemperature[day]
  if(tempDiff > 0){printText = paste('The temperature on', DaysOfTheWeek[day+1], 'should warm up by', abs(tempDiff), 'degrees')
  } else if(tempDiff < 0){printText = paste('The temperature on', DaysOfTheWeek[day+1], 'should cool down by', abs(tempDiff), 'degrees')
  } else if(tempDiff == 0){printText = paste('The temperature on', DaysOfTheWeek[day+1], 'will be the same as yesterday')}
  print(printText)
}
```

Output:

```
[1] "The temperature on Tuesday should cool down by 1 degrees"
[1] "The temperature on Wednesday should warm up by 3 degrees"
[1] "The temperature on Thursday should warm up by 5 degrees"
[1] "The temperature on Friday should warm up by 7 degrees"
[1] "The temperature on Saturday will be the same as yesterday"
[1] "The temperature on Sunday should cool down by 2 degrees"
```

Comment: Thanks, it actually did get closer to what the actual output should be. I just added the abs() function to the second if-else statement to get positive values for degrees. Only problem is that instead of the pasted statement for saturday saying that it should cool down by 0 degrees, it should really have an output of 'same as yesterday'. I'm trying to figure that bit out. But thanks again for this clarification.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much. I love that it's simplified.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ifelse statement to do the trick

```
PredictedTemperature = c(-10, -11, -8, -3, 4, 4, 2) 
DaysOfTheWeek = c('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday')
final <- data.frame(DaysOfTheWeek,PredictedTemperature)
final$condition <- ifelse(lead(final$PredictedTemperature,1) - final$PredictedTemperature > 0,paste('The temperature on', DaysOfTheWeek, 'should warm up by', tempDiff = lead(final$PredictedTemperature,1)- final$PredictedTemperature, 'degrees'),ifelse(lead(final$PredictedTemperature,1) - final$PredictedTemperature <= 0 ,paste('The temperature on', DaysOfTheWeek, 'should cool down by', tempDiff = lead(final$PredictedTemperature,1)- final$PredictedTemperature, 'degrees'),paste('The temperature on', DaysOfTheWeek, 'will be the same as yesterday')))
```